# Archivos temporales con GDAL en Python

Tags: python, archivo

Intento crear un archivo temporal de una imagen que extraigo de un PDF con GDAL.
Soy muy nueva en Python, lo siento si estoy haciendo algo mal. El error es que al parecer debo enviarle el primer parámetro a `gdal.Translate` de tipo `String`, es el nombre de la imagen que voy a crear y yo le mando el archivo temporal que cree. (Siguiendo los ejemplos).
Este es mi código:

```
def get_corners(path):
temporal = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.png')
tmp_ds = gdal.Warp('temp', path, format = 'MEM', dstSRS = 'EPSG:3857')
gdal.Translate(temporal, tmp_ds, format = 'PNG', width= 3000, height=  3000)
with open(temporal, 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
    img = b64encode(data)
    image = img.decode('utf-8')
```

Gracias.

Comment: Hola Monicatffe, ¿qué sistema operativo usas? Es trivial en sistemas *nix pero no en Windows....

Comment: MacOS Catalina :p

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que `gdal.Translate` espera que se le pase la ruta al archivo, en forma de cadena, y no un descriptor directamente.

La solución pasa por usar el atributo `name` para obtener la ruta del archivo. En sistemas *nix no debe haber ningún problema en reabrir el archivo mientras este continúe abierto:

```
import tempfile
from osgeo import gdal


def get_corners(path):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.png') as temporal:
        tmp_ds = gdal.Warp('temp', path, format='MEM', dstSRS='EPSG:3857')
        gdal.Translate(temporal.name, tmp_ds, format='PNG', width=3000, height=3000)
        data = temporal.read()

    img = b64encode(data)
    image = img.decode('utf-8')
```